# Jenkins execute shell scp

Tags: scp, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build where I am trying to copy a war file from one vm to another.  I want to do this using `scp`.  I've tried running this in the shell outside of Jenkins and everything works fine.  Trying to automate it is a little tricky.  I need to provide a password in order to use `sudo` and also need to enter a password for the vm I am copying to.

In the Jenkins build logs, I am seeing that the build is failing after I execute the custom shell script.

The command I am running in the Jenkins build is

```
echo 'password' | sudo -S scp -P 5555 application.war user@15.15.15.15:/JBoss/standalone/deployments
```

The output is

```
[sudo] password for jenkins: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for jenkins: 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

I don't have any users setup for Jenkins, so I am not understanding the `[sudo] password for jenkins` error.

I realize that there are Jenkins plugins to achieve what I am trying to do, but none of them are working for me at the moment, which is probably due to bad server configuration.  That is why I want to use `scp` in a custom shell script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> echo 'password' | sudo -S scp ...
> ```

no, it is not a good idea and it does not work, as discussed many times around SE. SSH flushes input before reading password. **You should set up ssh keys.**

If keys are not an option, there is also tool called `sshpass`, which you can use to provide password to `ssh`/`scp`. The last possibility is `expect` script, which can interact with interactive prompts.

Answer (score 0):

Please try publishoverssh plugin. Check below link for reference:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/